Page with Google's reCAPTCHA gets massive traffic peaks from Googlebot, why?
In a web application there is a contact form that is protected by Google's reCAPTCHA.
The page as such is set to NOINDEX, FOLLOW:
<meta content="noindex, follow" name="robots">

However, in the Cloudflare Traffic Dashboard I see huge peaks of Googlebot Traffic to that page, sometimes over 20k requests to that page within an hour!!
Does anybody have an idea what's going on here?
